# Why is my SSL handshake failing before sending any SSL messages?

Tags: ios, macos, ssl, secure-transport

I'm trying to connect an iOS client to an OS X server using TLS 1.2 with Apple's Secure Transport APIs. I had BSD sockets communication working correctly, and I'm having a lot of trouble getting it wrapped with TLS. As far as I can tell from Wireshark's output, the SSL handshake isn't even really getting started, so it's possible that I'm setting up SSL incorrectly on one side or the other but I'm not sure what I could be doing wrong.

Server side:

```
void establish_connection(int sockfd) {
  SSLContexRef sslContext = SSLCreateContext(kCFAllocatorDefault, kSSLServerSide, kSSLStreamType);
  SSLSetIOFuncs(sslContext, readFromSocket, writeToSocket);
  SSLSetConnection(sslContext, (SSLConnectionRef)(long)sockfd);
  SSLSetProtocolVersionMin(sslContext, kTLSProtocol12);

  // Get self-signed certificate from p12 data
  CFDataRef cert_data = CFDataCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, cert_p12, cert_p12_len);
  CFArrayRef items = NULL;
  const void *options_keys[] = { kSecImportExportPassphrase };
  const void *options_values[] = { CFSTR("password") };
  CFDictionaryRef options = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, options_keys, options_values, 1, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
  SecPKCS12Import(cert_data, options, &items);
  CFRelease(options);
  CFDictionaryRef item = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(items, 0);
  SecIdentityRef identity = (SecIdentityRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(item, kSecImportItemIdentity);
  CFArrayRef certs = CFArrayCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, (const void **)&identity, 1, NULL);
  SSLSetCertificate(sslContext, certs);

  // Fails with errSSLProtocol
  SSLHandshake(sslContext);
  ...
}
```

Client side:

```
void establish_connection(int server_sockfd) {
  SSLContextRef sslContext = SSLCreateContext(kCFAllocatorDefault, kSSLClientSide, kSSLStreamType);
  SSLSetIOFuncs(sslContext, readFromSocket, writeToSocket);
  SSLSetConnection(sslContext, (SSLConnectionRef)server_sockfd);
  SSLSetProtocolVersionMin(sslContext, kTLSProtocol12);

  // Fails with errSSLProtocol
  SSLHandshake(sslContext);
  ...
}
```

Wireshark's dump of the attempted handshake:

```
Source Destination Protocol Length Info
client server      TCP      78     50743 > 49754 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=16 TSval=365690143 TSecr=0 SACK_PERM=1
server client      TCP      78     49754 > 50743 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=16 TSval=666304222 TSecr=365690143 SACK_PERM=1
client server      TCP      66     50743 > 49754 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=131760 Len=0 TSval=365690468 TSecr=666304222
server client      TCP      66     [TCP Window Update] 49754 > 50743 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=131760 Len=0 TSval=666304252 TSecr=365690468
server client      TCP      66     49754 > 50743 [FIN, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=131760 Len=0 TSval=666304281 TSecr=365690468
client server      TCP      66     50743 > 49754 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=2 Win=131760 Len=0 TSval=365690498 TSecr=666304281
server client      TCP      66     [TCP Dup ACK 9099#1] 49754 > 50743 [ACK] Seq=2 Ack=1 Win=131760 Len=0 TSval=666304283 TSecr=365690498
```

Using Wireshark to try to diagnose the problem, I don't even see any SSL handshake messages. I see the TCP connection get established, then close immediately with no packets of length greater than 0. What could I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the full stack trace, and/or more specifics on the packets that are exchanged?

Comment: I've edited the question to add the Wireshark dump for the attempted handshake.

Comment: The Wireshark dump looks like it shows a half close from the server, and not a full close.  Still, the server shouldn't be closing if it expects to negotiate an SSL connection.  I am not familiar with the iOS calls, but I wonder if you need to initiate the handshake from both sides, or if it should be done only from one side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the problem was that I had my IO functions implemented incorrectly. I'm pasting in socket IO functions that seem to work, but the requirements for the IO functions are not that well documented so I may be missing something.

```
OSStatus readFromSocket(SSLConnectionRef connection, void *data, size_t *dataLength) {
  int sockfd = (int)connection;
  size_t bytesRequested = *dataLength;
  ssize_t status = read(sockfd, data, bytesRequested);
  if (status > 0) {
    *dataLength = status;
    if (bytesRequested > *dataLength)
      return errSSLWouldBlock;
    else
      return noErr;
  } else if (0 == status) {
    *dataLength = 0;
    return errSSLClosedGraceful;
  } else {
    *dataLength = 0;
    switch (errno) {
      case ENOENT:
        return errSSLClosedGraceful;
      case EAGAIN:
        return errSSLWouldBlock;
      case ECONNRESET:
        return errSSLClosedAbort;
      default:
        return errSecIO;
    }
    return noErr;
  }
}

OSStatus writeToSocket(SSLConnectionRef connection, const void *data, size_t *dataLength) {
  int sockfd = (int)connection;
  size_t bytesToWrite = *dataLength;
  ssize_t status = write(sockfd, data, bytesToWrite);
  if (status > 0) {
    *dataLength = status;
    if (bytesToWrite > *dataLength)
      return errSSLWouldBlock;
    else
      return noErr;
  } else if (0 == status) {
    *dataLength = 0;
    return errSSLClosedGraceful;
  } else {
    *dataLength = 0;
    if (EAGAIN == errno) {
      return errSSLWouldBlock;
    } else {
      return errSecIO;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Greg, I am also working on the same. Can u please suggest me what to do next after handshaking. I will be very thankful to you..:)

Comment: If the handshake is successful, you should be able to just use `SSLRead` and `SSLWrite` to communicate over the connection the same way you'd use `read` and `write` with standard sockets.

Comment: Yes I have implemented it in late night.. But anyways appreciating your advise and help.. thanx alot.. Happy Coding..:)

Comment: From my experiments, it seems the key is to return errSSLWouldBlock from the read callback whenever you didn't read exactly as many bytes as requested. Just leaving this here in case someone else needs to implement custom callbacks and sees similar issues.

Comment: Another caveat: The SSL layer might ask the callback for data even if it still has data in its buffer. This is particularly annoying when the underlying layer is blocking, so the application might only get the buffered data after the lower layer timed out. The solution to that problem is to use ioctl (or whatever is relevant for your lower layer) to check whether the lower layer has data available. If no data is available, return errSSLWouldBlock from the callback, even if that means your return no data to the SSL layer.